# append не добавляет в HTML необходимый текст

Tags: javascript

Необходимо было написать функцию сортировки для сортировки массива и отображения в HTML, чтобы получить результат как на картинке.

Проблема в том, что функция `filter` написана и работает, но не работает функция `DrawArray`. Пытался удалять `div` — безрезультатно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="ru-RU" lang="ru-RU">

</html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="blocks-wrapper">
            <div class="block" id="block-6">6</div>
            <div class="block" id="block-2">2</div>
            <div class="block" id="block-3">3</div>
            <div class="block" id="block-1">1</div>
            <div class="block" id="block-7">7</div>
            <div class="block" id="block-4">4</div>
            <div class="block" id="block-8">8</div>
            <div class="block" id="block-5">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```js
var array = [6, 2, 3, 1, 7, 4, 8, 5]

function filter(array) {
  for (let j = array.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
    for (let i = 0; i < j; i++) {
      if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
        let temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

function DrawArray() {
    var wrapper = $(".blocks-wrapper");
    wrapper.html('');
    
    array.forEach(element => {
        wrapper.append(`<div class="block" id="block-${element}">${element}</div>`);
    });
    wrapper.addClass('reDrawed');

    setTimeout(() => {
        wrapper.removeClass('reDrawed');
    },1000)
}
filter(array)
DrawArray()
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anek+Latin:wght@400&display=swap');

:root{
    --color-1:hsla(0  , 100%, 45%, 0.7);
    --color-2:hsla(60 , 100%, 45%, 0.7);
    --color-3:hsla(90 , 100%, 45%, 0.7);
    --color-4:hsla(135, 100%, 45%, 0.7);
    --color-5:hsla(180, 100%, 45%, 0.7);
    --color-6:hsla(225, 100%, 45%, 0.7);
    --color-7:hsla(270, 100%, 45%, 0.7);
    --color-8:hsla(315, 100%, 45%, 0.7);
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Anek Latin', sans-serif;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}
.blocks-wrapper{
    max-width: 450px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}
.block{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;

    transition: all 0.3s;
    animation-name: arrAnim;
    animation-duration: 300ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#block-1 {background-color: var(--color-1);}
#block-2 {background-color: var(--color-2);}
#block-3 {background-color: var(--color-3);}
#block-4 {background-color: var(--color-4);}
#block-5 {background-color: var(--color-5);}
#block-6 {background-color: var(--color-6);}
#block-7 {background-color: var(--color-7);}
#block-8 {background-color: var(--color-8);}

.blocks-wrapper.reDrawed .block:nth-child(1) {animation-delay: 0ms;}
.blocks-wrapper.reDrawed .block:nth-child(2) {animation-delay: 40ms;}
.blocks-wrapper.reDrawed .block:nth-child(3) {animation-delay: 80ms;}
.blocks-wrapper.reDrawed .block:nth-child(4) {animation-delay: 120ms;}
.blocks-wrapper.reDrawed .block:nth-child(5) {animation-delay: 160ms;}
.blocks-wrapper.reDrawed .block:nth-child(6) {animation-delay: 200ms;}
.blocks-wrapper.reDrawed .block:nth-child(7) {animation-delay: 240ms;}
.blocks-wrapper.reDrawed .block:nth-child(8) {animation-delay: 280ms;}

@keyframes arrAnim {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Дождитесь загрузки DOM и потом вызывайте функцию: `$(() => { DrawArray(); });`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Comment: P.S. @ObrubovD, а почему бы вместо функции `filter` не написать просто `array.sort()` ?

Comment: По заданию нельзя было использовать сторонние функции для сортировки , то есть задача была написать именно функцию сортировки